# SQLite query select best option depending on a max value

Tags: sqlite, max, unique, combinations

I have a probably pretty hard question/situation:
I have a database to divide several tasks to some workers.
In the next example I have two tasks (Task 1 and Task 2) and 4 Employee's(1, 2, 3 and 4)
The maximum employee's that works on 1 task is three. Therefore I have 3 columns to get all possible options (in this example, not every option is shown!). The last column is a value which indicate how good the option is (the higher the number, the better).

The goal is to get the most optimal situation which means:

- Every employee have to do one task (and cannot do 2 tasks)
- The sum of the values is the highest possible value

  > ```
  > +------------+------------+------------+------+--------+
  > | Employee_1 | Employee_2 | Employee_3 | Task | Value  |
  > +------------+------------+------------+------+--------+
  > |          1 |            |            |    1 | 5.0    |
  > |          2 |            |            |    1 | -2.5   |
  > |          3 |            |            |    1 | 1.0    |
  > |          4 |            |            |    1 | 0.5    |
  > |          1 |          2 |            |    1 | 0.5    |
  > |          1 |          4 |            |    1 | 5,0    |  
  > |          1 |          2 |          3 |    1 | 0.33   |
  > |          2 |          3 |            |    1 | -4.5   |
  > |          2 |          3 |          4 |    1 | -6.5   |
  > |          3 |          4 |            |    1 | 3.0    |
  > |          1 |            |            |    2 | 1.0    |
  > |          2 |            |            |    2 | 2.0    |
  > |          3 |            |            |    2 | -5.0   |
  > |          4 |            |            |    2 | 3.0    |
  > |          1 |          2 |            |    2 | -2.0   |
  > |          1 |          2 |          3 |    2 | -3.5   |
  > |          2 |          3 |            |    2 | 5.0    |
  > |          2 |          3 |          4 |    2 | 0.5    |
  > |          3 |          4 |            |    2 | 2.0    |
  > +------------+------------+------------+------+--------+
  > ```

As you can see: sometimes it is better for the productivity:
Employee 1 gets a value of 5 on task 1
Employee 4 gets a value of 0.5 on task 1
Employee 1 and 3 gets a value of 5,0 on task 1
In this situation it is better that Employee 1 and 3 works separate and the query should give both lines:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------+
| Employee_1 | Employee_2  | Employee_3 | Task  | Value   |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------+
|          1 |             |            |     1 | 5.0     |
|          4 |             |            |     1 | 0.5     |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

The real solution for this example should be:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------+
| Employee_1 | Employee_2  | Employee_3 | Task  | Value   |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------+
|          1 |             |            |     1 | 5.0     |
|          2 |           3 |            |     2 | 5.0     |
|          4 |             |            |     2 | 3.0     |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Since employee 1 has a very high value on its own on task 1
Employee 3 is really bad on his own, but together with employee 2 they do great on task 2
Employee 4 is the only one who is left en this employee is pretty good at task 2.

The problem is to write the query to get this result

Comment: What have you tried? Are you asking us to solve the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) in SQL?

Comment: It might be possible to brute force all possibilities with [recursive CTEs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), but that would be silly. Why is this required to be implemented in SQL?